# Starcraft Battle.net US Account (EU User)

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

I am from Europe (Romania) and I need to get a US Battle.net Account since I just bought the US version.

Is it possible?

**Thank you.**

Comment: why don't you just try and see if you can? I also hear from people, that you can merge your accounts if that's what you are after.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***So here is the solution:***

If you have an EU Account and a US CD-Key just go to **us.battle.net** and Sign In with your EU Account. Then add the CD-Key to your Account and download the **enUS** version of the game.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can go to us.battle.net and activate it. You may have to make a new account, though.

Comment: No need for a new account, you can sign in with your EU one.